# Let $I = [0, 1) ∪ [2, 3]$ with the usual metric.Prove that the closure of $B$ is not the closed ball of center $0$, radius $2$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $I = [0, 1) ∪ [2, 3]$ with the usual metric. Let $B = I(0, 2)$ be the open ball of center $x$ and radius $1$. Prove that the closure of $B$ is not the closed ball of center $0$, radius $2$.

The usual metric being the absolute value function on $\mathbb{R}$.

$\bar A=\{x∈I: \forall V(x),V(x)∩A≠ϕ\}$ : closure of a set $A$,

Need to show the $\bar B \neq cl(0,2)$ I think I am interpreting this question correctly, it won't be equal because the closed ball centers at $0$ with radius $2$ has points such as $z \in [1,2)$ whereas $ I = [0, 1) ∪ [2, 3]$ so $z \notin B(0,2) $ something like $z=1.5$ is not in $I$.

Do I hae the idea correct? Before I try to prove something.

Comment: Your statement of the problem makes no sense. I suspect that $B$ is supposed to be the open ball of radius $2$ centred at $0$, and you’re to prove that its closure in $I$ is not the closed ball of radius $2$ centred at $0$. If my guess is correct, $B=[0,1)=\operatorname{cl}B$. Now what (in $I$, not $\Bbb R$) is the closed ball of radius $2$ centred at $0$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott see I figured that too, I copied the question exactly as it was.

Comment: In that case the question is defective, I’m afraid.